# PHP problems, fread throwing errors

Tags: php, mysql, fread

part of my code is below, i am using a php script to read files in a directory, these files are constantly written and this script searches for them and writes their contents to a database. The error i receive is that when a file is still being written and this script detects it it tries to fread the file, the $data it receives doesn't match the file size as it has changed and an error is thrown.

My question is how to ensure the file has been written successfully before this script reads the file. Thanks in advance.

```
$myfile = fopen($filename, "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
$data = fread($myfile,filesize($filename));
fclose($myfile);
```

Some reading would suggest it seems best to include the code below on the script that writes the files.

```
if (flock($file,LOCK_EX)){
  fwrite($file,"Write something");
  flock($file,LOCK_UN);
} else {
  echo "Error locking file!";
}
```

Comment: try to open in `binary`-mode, `fopen($filename, 'rb');` otherwise you will open file in text-mode, and code 0x1a signals about end of file, and you can't to be ensure w/o some lock system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There could be many methods, but the most common method would be file locking.  Acquire a lock when writing to the file, release the lock when complete.  Check for a lock before reading the file.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php